# Xamarin 'hello world' app won't run, emulatpr too big

Tags: xamarin

Decided to give Xamarin a shot. Installed xamarin, launched Visual Studio, created a new blank android project, ran it, created an account, checked the 'business trial' option.

First time I ran it I got a popup saying could not contact device.

Second time I ran it I got an error saying Could not connect to logcat.

Third time I ran it the emulator appeared and showed me this:

[image: Emulator screenshot]

I waited a while but nothing happened.

I tried stopping it and running it again, I got the first error again.

In between these steps, I have made no changes, just stopped and started.

Any idea why it's being so useless? I can't seem to do anything with the emulator because stuff is too big to click. Any advice welcome, it's a bit off putting that this is my first experience with Xamarin!

Comment: Maybe you should give a try to Xamarin Android Player: https://xamarin.com/android-player

Comment: That has nothing to do with Xamarin. Your problems are with Google's Android emulator, installing and configuring HAXE can help with performance issues but it is still running via emulation... IMHO you should be using either Visual Studio Emulator for Android, GenyMotion or Xamarin's Android Player. Since you are on Windows, start by using VS Emulator and your experience should improve greatly: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to try running the latest Xamarin Android Player. You can find the downloads for both Windows and Mac here: https://xamarin.com/android-player

The instructions are pretty precise, should you have any issues during the installation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/

Comment: Cheers, I've installed it, and after a reboot and running it I could select an emulator to download, which magically appeared in visual studio. Selecting that, it launched first time with no problems, and the hello world app runs perfectly. Thanks!